# Address of structure pointer in function is 0x1

Tags: c++, pointers

When I make c++ project  address of p1 in output is 0x1

```
struct f_52
{
    char s[10];
    int *pi;
};
struct f_51
{
    int i;
    char *pc;
    f_52 *ps;
};
void function_1()
{
    struct f_51 *p1;
    struct f_52 *p3;
    cout<<"Address p1:\t"<<p1<<endl;
    cout<<"Address p3:\t"<<p3<<endl;
    p1 = new f_51;
    cout<<"================================\n";
    cout<<"Address p1:\t"<<p1<<endl;
    cout<<"        p1.i:\t"<<p1->i<<endl
        <<"        p1.pc:\t"<<*(p1->pc)<<endl
        <<"Address p1.ps:\t"<<p1->ps<<endl;
    //cout<<"        p3.pi:\t"<<*(p3->pi)<<endl;
}
int main()
{
    function_1();
}
```

Output:

> Address p1:0x1
>
> Address p2:0x80489e2
>
> ...

Is it correct and why 0x1?

Comment: In C++ uninitialized local variables *are* uninitialized. Their values are *indeterminate* and attempting to use them in *any* way without initialization leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Comment: Which output line of two `Address p1:` you posted? The first one outputs an initialized pointer `p1`.

Comment: `cout<<"Address p1:\t"<<p1<<endl;` does not print "the address of p1". It prints the address *stored in p1*. To print the address of `p1` do `cout<<"Address p1:\t"<<&p1<<endl;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of of your pointers is initialized, and therefore they have random values. Change anything to your code of wait for a different moon phase, and the values will change. Never use unassigned pointers!